# Как сгруппировать данные только в одном столбце?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, case, dbeaver

Имею таблицу:

| id | name | comments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | com1 |
| 1 | A | com2 |
| 2 | B | com3 |
| 2 | B | com4 |

Каким запросом могу получить такой результат?

| id | name | comments |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | com1, com2 |
| 2 | B | com3, com4 |

Без разницы com-ы через запятую или друг под другом главное, чтобы были в одной ячейке.
Спасибо!

Comment: попробуйте через `string_agg` -> https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#:~:text=No-,string_agg,-(%20value%20text

Comment: используя `string_agg` нужно сгруппировать `id` и `name`

Answer (score 0):

Демо таблица:

```
create table dbeaver (
  id int,
  name varchar(20),
  comments varchar(100)
  );
insert into dbeaver (id,name,comments) values (1,'A','com1');
insert into dbeaver (id,name,comments) values (1,'A','com2');
insert into dbeaver (id,name,comments) values (2,'B','com3');
insert into dbeaver (id,name,comments) values (2,'B','com4');
```

Решение:

```
SELECT id,min(name),string_agg(comments,',')
FROM dbeaver
GROUP BY id
```

[Решение на db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wejWwspevcVNm3yBzuRKDL/1)